# newConditionalFormatRule based on value and other cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

Im trying to use app-script `newConditionalFormatRule` to set color of the cell based on other cell.

Lets say i have this:

```
A1 = 40
B1 = 90
```

then i would like A1 to get the color green, since its lower than B1.
I want B1 to get red, since its higher than A1.

Is there a way so i can create this behaviour in a rulset?

like:

```
var rule3 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .//check other cell if greater thing.
      .setBackground("#EEED09")
      .setRanges([range])
      .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example creates a conditional formatting rule that sets a gradient of colors from green to red for values in the range. The lowest value is colored green, the highest is red.

```
function CFtest2() {
  var theSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var area = theSheet.getRange('A1:B1');
  var newRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule();
  newRule
  .setRanges([area])
  .setGradientMinpoint('#00FF00')
  .setGradientMidpointWithValue('#FFFFFF', SpreadsheetApp.InterpolationType.PERCENTILE, '50')
  .setGradientMaxpoint('#FF0000')
  .build();
  theSheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules([newRule]);
};
```